# Is there a way to use Angular Signals outside Angular, in a regular Typescript project?

Tags: angular, angular-signals

I'm wondering if there is a way to import just the angular signals in a typescript project, so that I could keep using the same syntax and semantic in other projects, instead of having to install different signals libs..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Angular signals are part of Angular, here is a quote of the [Signal RFC](https://github.com/angular/angular/discussions/49683).

> We did discuss the possibility of publishing an independent signal
> library but didn't do so initially for the following reasons:
>
> it is still in the early stages and we don't want to publish before
> going through the RFC feedback and settling on the exact API shape
> there are parts of the library that deeply integrate with the Angular
> internals (effects scheduling and cleanup is the most notable example)
> there is some practical friction in publishing a new package We will
> definitely consider publishing a separate NPM package if there is
> value in it - please leave feedback in the RFC if you would like to
> see Angular signals library to be available as a separate NPM package.

This means the signals are not meant to be used outside Angular because they are an integral part of Angular.

There are other Signal libraries you could use though.